# Saving list without losing any

Tags: python

I'm trying to save all the results and the only result I'm getting is saving one part one line. I want to save the entire result but I don't know what is happening. Thanks

[image: code]

[image: Result]

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image. And result as well if that too can be represented in text.

Comment: Hey, update the question following the rules here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hint: re-read the documentation for `open()`, and specially what the `"w"` flag means.

Answer (score 0):

`'w'` means write - in this case it will override whatever the content of the file is, every time you try to `open()`

What you're looking for is `'a'` - amend to previous content.